# Custom taxonomy list in two columns

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I am using this to get taxonomy list. For each post, there are more than 20 terms. How can I get them in two columns.

```
echo '<ul>'; echo strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'trade', '<li>', '</li><li>', '</li>' ) ,'<li>'); echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [get_the_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) instead of get_the_term_list. This will give you an array.
You can then either loop through and start a new `ul` at the half-way point, or [array_slice](https://www.php.net/array_slice) the array first, then build two `ul`s.